# sed match exactly 8 times a certain match

Tags: regex, sed

My Goal is the following:
`sed` should replace a line with 8 times `;` but when the line has 9 or 7 .. then it should not.
I tried the following:

```
echo ";asdf;asdfsadf;sdafasdf;asdfsdfasd;;;;" | sed -E 's/((.*;.*){8})/ /p'
echo ";asdf;asdfsadf;sdafasdf;asdfsdfasd;;;;" | sed -E 's/\<(.*;.*){8}\>/ /p'
```

but nothing works when there are 9 or more `;` in the line.
Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Can you please give an example of inputs, expected outputs, and the current outputs you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
^([^;]*;){8}[^;]*$
```

This part `^([^;]*;){8}` repeats 8 times matching 0+ times any char except a `;`, then match `;`

After that it will match again 0+ times any char except `;` till the end of the string.

**In parts**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Start group

  - `[^;]*;` Match 0+ times any char except `;`
- `){8}` Close group and repeat 8 times
- `[^;]*` Match 0+ times any char except `;`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BDzERW/1) | [Bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19ByTqxOCUNTBQnAhnFKYlpCJEUENsaCJQUahSKU1MUdF0V1Iv14zSi46xjtaw1qy1qwSwV/SDXAB9HZ1dfV78QfXUuahhtSTujzbEa/f8/AA)

For example

```
echo ";asdf;asdfsadf;sdafasdf;asdfsdfasd;;;;" | sed -E 's/^([^;]*;){8}[^;]*$/ /'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
^([^;]*?;[^;]*?){8}$
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/9y01wg/2)

````
echo ";asdf;asdfsadf;sdafasdf;asdfsdfasd;;;;" | sed -E 's/^([^;]*?;[^;]*?){8}$/REPLACEMENT_WORD/gm;t;d'```
````

With 8 `;` outputs

```
REPLACEMENT_WORD
```

And

````
echo ";asdf;asdfsadf;sdafasdf;asdfsdfasd;;;;;" | sed -E 's/^([^;]*?;[^;]*?){8}$/REPLACEMENT_WORD/gm;t;d'```
````

With 9 `;` outputs nothing.

Comment: echo ";asdf;asdfsadf;sdafasdf;asdfsdfasd;;;;;;" | sed  -E 's/^(?:[^;]*?;[^;]*?){8}$/ /g'
sed: -e Ausdruck #1, Zeichen 28: Der vorherige reguläre Ausdruck ist nicht korrekt.

Comment: Try ```echo ";asdf;asdfsadf;sdafasdf;asdfsdfasd;;;;" | sed -E 's/^([^;]*?;[^;]*?){8}$/REPLACEMENT_WORD/gm;t;d'```, I forgot that SED doesn't accept non capturing groups. I modify my answer.

Comment: Sed doesn't understand `*?` either. Why was this accepted?

Comment: Hum... don't know. Maybe more testing is needed before accepting this solution @LordNico. I'm not a professional ;)